# Multiple Schengen visa at the same time

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I currently have a multiple-entries tourist visa for Italy (its valid for 1 year from mid May 2016 to mid May 2017).

Now I will be travelling to Germany directly (inbound and outbound between July and December 2016) and I will stay in Germany also and only in Germany. I know I have to apply for German visa now because I will travel directy to and from Germany and I will spend the most time (100%) there. But the question is:

1. What will happen to my Italian visa? Will it be cancelled? Will I have to cancel it? Can I keep both since I be using my Italian visa also for travels and stays only in Italy?
2. Can/will Germany award me a 1-year tourist visa (90 days in 180 days) also based on my Italian visa? I mean if one Schengen country issued me this type of visa why not can the other country give me the same if they require I get one from their country since I be staying there the most time, right?
3. How to actually ask for a 1-year German multiple-entry tourist visa, because my current Italian visa was not specifically asked for, but a nice welcomed surprise.

Comment: Have you already traveled on your Italian visa?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid - Yes, I did travel and stay in Italy already and also made a short 4 day direct travel/stay in Germany with my Italian visa, but now I plan to direct travel/stay in Germany for atleast 6 weeks. So I am not sure what to do, how it works.

Comment: @raulbaros, bit of OT, but was this italian visa application your first application?

Comment: @Davinder - yes, it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your multiple-entry visa is **issued by** Italy, but not exclusively "for" Italy.

It is valid for the entire Schengen area, and you're perfectly entitled to make short visits to Germany (or any other Schengen state), especially when you have already used if for the Italy trip you described in your original application.

Here "short visits" means anything that complies with the general 90/180 day rule, so your planned 6-week visit is still completely good for your current visa. It also doesn't matter whether you're traveling to Germany directly or through another Schengen state.

The entire point of issuing a visa with long validity and multiple entries is that you've now been vetted enough to cover *all subsequent short visits to anywhere in the Schengen area* for as long as the visa is valid for. Part of the Schengen arrangement is that member states such as Germany and Italy trust each other to do such vetting on each other's behalf.

In fact you *can't* get a German short-stay visa as long as the Italian one is valid -- because it would not allow you to do anything that the existing visa doesn't *already* allow you to do.

In principle you can ask to have your Italian visa revoked and then apply for a German one from scratch -- but *because* that would be utterly pointless, it's likely to raise suspicion that you're trying some kind of hustle that the consular personnel cannot figure out, and your application might be treated with extraordinary scrutiny, risking a refusal. So *don't* do that!

You're probably being confused the rules about main destinations. These rule govern **which Schengen state can process a given visa application**. Once you have managed to get a visa application processed (and your claims in that application were truthful), those rules are irrelevant to you. There's no rule saying that *each trip you make* has to be covered by a visa issued by the main destination for that trip. Only for *trips that you want to use as reason for applying to a visa* does the rule kick in and tell you where to send that application. But in this case you don't need to detail your Germany trip in *any* visa application, so it is immaterial where you *would* have sent that application if you need to get a new visa for the trip.

**TL;DR** Your existing visa is all you need. Do not apply for another one!

Comment: @Hennig Makholm - thank you for your clear and useful explanation, you solved my query, I fully understand. But to be honest I am a little bit worried about this rule that you have to apply for a visa for the country where you spend the most time in?

Comment: @raulbaros: See new second-to-last paragraph. You can think of the rule that way: You put together a visa application, containing details of the _first_ trip you need a visa for. Now you need to figure out which consulate to send that application to. That will be the main destination of the trip you describe in the application. If they happen to issue you a visa that is valid for other future trips too, then great! This means you don't have to put together an application for those future trip, and therefore you never need to ask yourself "which consulate should I send that to".

Comment: The function of the rule is **how to distribute workload among consulates**, and to make sure prospective travelers will not "forum-shop" between consulates in the hope of finding the easiest one to get past. But in your situation you _don't need to involve a consulate at all_ for your Germany trip, and there's no question of making sure you don't apply to any "wrong" consulate.

Comment: perfect, I fully understand. Really, I cannot thank you enough for your help, I was really confused and didnt know what to expect or do. Your explanation is very much appreciated. Thank you so much. Best wishes!